# Strange behaviour from push (hash)

Tags: perl

I fully understand that a hash is unsorted, but I was under the impression that it always keeps keys/values relationship.

I am not understanding this behaviour at all. When I push from an array, do some de-duplication and then print key's, sub-keys and values, I get the desired result:

```
my @Input = ("Crockery breakable plates",
             "Crockery breakable glasses",
             "Cutlery bendable forks",
             "Cutlery bendable spoons"
            );

my %store = ();
foreach (@Input) {
    my ($key, $key2, $value) = split;
    chomp ($key, $key2, $value);
    my $combine = "$key-$key2-$value";
    push @arr, "$key-$key2-$value";
   # push @{$store{$combine}}, "$key-$key2-$value";
 }

foreach (@arr) {
($key, $key2, $value) =split /-/;
 chomp ($key, $key2, $value);
     $seen{$key}++ || print "1. $key\n";
      $seen{$key2}++ || print "2. -- $key2\n";
       $seen{$value}++ || print "3. ----$value\n";
    }
```

Which simply will print this each time:

```
1. Crockery
2. -- breakable
3. ----plates
3. ----glasses
1. Cutlery
2. -- bendable
3. ----forks
3. ----spoons
```

Then I do basically the same thing, but push to

```
my @Input = ("Crockery breakable plates",
             "Crockery breakable glasses",
             "Cutlery bendable forks",
             "Cutlery bendable spoons"
            );

my %store = ();
foreach (@Input) {
    my ($key, $key2, $value) = split;
    chomp ($key, $key2, $value);
    my $combine = "$key-$key2-$value";
   # push @arr, "$key-$key2-$value";
    push @{$store{$combine}}, "$key-$key2-$value";
 }

foreach my $k(keys %store) {
    ($key, $key2, $value) = split /-/, $k;
    chomp ($key, $key2, $value);
         $seen{$key}++ || print "1. $key\n";
          $seen{$key2}++ || print "2. -- $key2\n";
           $seen{$value}++ || print "3. ----$value\n";
    }
```

Which prints random results each time:

```
1. Cutlery
2. -- bendable
3. ----forks
1. Crockery
2. -- breakable
3. ----plates   
3. ----spoons    < --- not Crockery
3. ----glasses
```

The only real difference (which I can see) here is that I split the key name, but that layout is still the same as the array name.

So the question, Can someone help me in understanding why and how I can fix this?

PS!! the reason I ask the question, I wanted to split my key name in my script, and not push another array, as I already push this key name once as I use it in another part of the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `||` from the `$seen{something}++ || print ...` constructions and you will see that the output is correct.

```
...
foreach my $k(keys %store) {
  ($key, $key2, $value) = split /-/, $k;
  chomp ($key, $key2, $value);
  $seen{$key}++ && print "*"; print "1. $key\n";
  $seen{$key2}++ && print "*"; print "2. -- $key2\n";
  $seen{$value}++ && print "*"; print "3. ----$value\n";
}
```

---

```
1. Cutlery
2. -- bendable
3. ----forks
1. Crockery
2. -- breakable
3. ----glasses
*1. Cutlery
*2. -- bendable
3. ----spoons
*1. Crockery
*2. -- breakable
3. ----plates
```

Any line that begins with `*` in the new script would not be output in the original script.

---

Note that if you sort the keys of `%store`, the second key and values will always be associated with the correct first key, as you wish:

```
foreach my $k (sort keys %store) {
#              ^^^^
     ($key, $key2, $value) = split /-/, $k;
     chomp ($key, $key2, $value);
     $seen{$key}++ || print "1. $key\n";
     $seen{$key2}++ || print "2. -- $key2\n";
     $seen{$value}++ || print "3. ----$value\n";
}
```

---

```
1. Crockery
2. -- breakable
3. ----glasses
3. ----plates
1. Cutlery
2. -- bendable
3. ----forks
3. ----spoons
```

though I guess you could still be confounded if the same value or key2 was associated with more than one key.

Comment: Perfect, that makes loads of sense, thanks a mill. Upvoted in the meanwhile as I have to wait  another 4 minutes to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: The `sort` option is exactly what I needed, Thanks a ton!!