# Multiple commands without one line in perl

Tags: perl

I wrote some [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451269/strange-behaviour-from-push-hash/50451368#50451368) that creates a hash from an array.

I created one liner `$seen`s to remove duplicates, instead of building hash tables, this will remove duplicates from my keys and values.

I realised that I cannot run multiple commands after `||` in newlines, (like a loop) but can only add them in one line, after `||`

The original portion:

```
...
foreach my $k (sort keys %store) {
     ($key, $key2, $value) = split /-/, $k;
     chomp ($key, $key2, $value);
     $seen{$key}++ || print "1. $key\n";
     $seen{$key2}++ || print "2. -- $key2\n";
     $seen{$value}++ || print "3. ----$value\n";
}
```

where I could print lines like this, but becomes tedious to maintain:

```
$seen{$value}++ || print "3. ----$value\n "something else";
```

I am actually creating an xml file, and placing all my text into a single line looks really bad and difficult to debug: So I really am looking for a method to instead do:

```
...
foreach my $k (sort keys %store) {
     ($key, $key2, $value) = split /-/, $k;
     chomp ($key, $key2, $value);
     $seen{$key}++ || {
                    print "1. $key\n";
                    print "that went well..";
                    ...
                  }

     $seen{$key2}++ || print "2. -- $key2\n";
     $seen{$value}++ || print "3. ----$value\n";
}
```

Is there a way to do this from one lines like these?

For any more clarity on this script, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451269/strange-behaviour-from-push-hash/50451368#50451368) which [@Mob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168657/mob) helped me alot.

Comment: Lines are not equal to statements in Perl. The `;` separates statements.

Comment: @simbabque my apologies, that is not what I meant to type, will fix now.

Comment: @Jacob: To be honest I don't understand your first sentence at all. I gathered what you wanted only from your code example. Could you fix the grammar please?

Comment: @Borodin Sorry, I tried to make it more understandable now.

Comment: If you are actually making an XML file, I'd urge you to _please_ use a parser.

Comment: @Sobrique Thanks, I am using a parser. This example I used in the question I just typed up as an example. My actual code does a lot more and would have been a bit too much to post here, but typically I use the parser in the loops instead of print in the examples. Thanks for your helpful comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$seen{$key}++ or do {
    print "1. $key\n";
    print "that went well..";
    ...
};
```

Comment: well, that was quite a surprise, so simple :\ Thanks a mill.

Comment: Or just `if ( not $seen{$key}++ ) { print print print }`.